# Pass python dictionary to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask, visualization

I have a Python + JS application connected to a PostgreSQL database. The database contains data about users in different countries, which is queried by the `server.py` file. The result of this query is a dictionary that would look something like this:
{'US': 2,
'CA': 5}

This dictionary needs to be passed to my `map.js` file, which populates a world map according to the country code (key) and volume (value). This dictionary updates with user activity, so it needs to be passed every time someone loads the map.

How can I pass the data over? It seems like I need to create a JSON file. I'm not sure how to create that file within python or how to call it from javascript.

I want to replace the hardcoded 'var data' values from `map.js` with my query results from `country_count` on `server.py`.

my `server.py`:

```
@app.route("/map")
def show_mapjs():

    country_count = {
        "US": 0, "CA": 0,
    }
    country_code = session.get("country_code")

    for country_code, _ in country_count.items():
        records_count = User_Records.query.filter_by(country_code=country_code).count()
        country_count[country_code] = records_count
    print(f"=== {country_count}")
    return country_count
```

(US & CA are initialized at 0 and the `records_count` query updates the count as user activity increases over time.)

my `map.js`:

```
fetch('/map')
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {

    var data = [
        {'id': 'US', 'value': 5},
        {'id': 'CA', 'value': 2}
    ]

        var dataSet = anychart.data.set(data);

        var mapData = dataSet.mapAs({ description: 'description' });

        var map = anychart.map();
```

Answer (score 1):

what a fun project!

Let's get the work under way.

On your server side,

```
import json

@app.route('/map')
def show_mapjs():
    country_count = {
        "US": 0, "CA": 0,
    }
    
    #place your own code here to get the data from the database#

    country_list = []      
    for country, count in country_count.items():
        country_list.append({"id": country, "value": count})
        
    # Serializing json 
    json_object = json.dumps(country_list)

    return json_object
```

On your client side,

First, include the below js libs in the HTML, so the next code can use it.

```
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.11.0/js/anychart-map.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/geodata/latest/custom/world/world.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-data-adapter.min.js"></script>
```

Use the map js function as below,

```
   <script>
    anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
        anychart.data.loadJsonFile("/map",
        function (data) {
            var map = anychart.map();
            map.geoData(anychart.maps.world);

            var dataSet = anychart.data.set(data);
            // set the series
            var series = map.choropleth(dataSet);
          
            // disable labels
            series.labels(false);

            // set the container
            map.container('container');
            map.draw();
          }
        );
      });
    </script>
```

You should do this way to avoid out-of-sync data loading and map rendering. This will ensure that the json is downloaded and then processed by the map.

Let me know if you have issues getting this working.